# app installed on SD card not receiving intent action

Tags: android, broadcastreceiver, android-sdcard, intentfilter

apps installed on sd card does not receive (using BroadCastReceiver) the intent.action_boot_completed nor intent.action_extra_applications_avaliable nor  intent.action.media_mounted. I would like to know what intent action the app which installed on sd could receive to start some kind of operation which mainly will be alarm manger with notification ? any help will be appreciated

p.s I have read all the documentation related to sd card install location with broadcast receiver but i think there at least one intent action the app could catch.

Answer (score 0):

Have you really checked with the [documentation about install location](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/install-location.html#ShouldNot)?

If you want an alarm manager to work, you need to register to mount external intents and start them there... as mentioned in the documentation...

Also it should react to the second mentioned intent:

> You can, however, register for the
>   ACTION_EXTERNAL_APPLICATIONS_AVAILABLE broadcast Intent, which will
>   notify your application when applications installed on external
>   storage have become available to the system again. At which time, you
>   can restart your Service.

Comment: thank you for your reply but this also wont start because if you checked the ACTION_EXTERNAL_APPLICATION_AVALIABLE documentation say:
'Note that the packages in this list do not receive this broadcast. The specified set of packages are now available on the system.' means that also the app installed on sd wont receive this action also

Comment: Interesting, so the documentation is unclear and argues against itself. After searching a bit, there is no real workaround for that...

Comment: thats what i reached too thanks for your answer but i was looking for other intent actions which could be catched by the sd installed apps is there some actions which received by the app installed on sd? other the early mentioned one